# publishing a node by using a dll in Visual Basic 2015(Windows)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have a similar problem as described [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/32202/communicating-between-ros-and-vb/) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/223231/building-dll-of-rosserial_windows/).
I want to send same IMU data from a Visual Basic .NET Application (WIndows) to a ROSmaster (Linux).

Therefore I am using ros_lib from rosserial. The Tutorial you can find [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Hello%20World#Installing_rosserial_windows).
This tutorial works well, but my appilcation which communicates with my IMU is written in vb.net. So my idea is to write a dll which published a node. Unfortunately several syntax errors appeared then.

Here is my header:

```
//SendMsgToROS.h
#ifdef SENDMSGDLL_EXPORTS
#define SENDMSGDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define SENDMSGDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

namespace SendMsg
{
    class Message
    {
    public:
        SENDMSGDLL_API int sendingMsg(int x, int y, int z);
    };
}
```

Here is my main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ros.h"
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "SendMsgToROS.h" //Header-File where namespace SendMsg and class Message are defined

using std::string;

namespace SendMsg
{
    int Message::sendingMsg(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
        char *ros_master = "1.1.3.1.1";//ID of ROS Masters'
        printf("Connecting to server at %s\n", ros_master);
        nh.initNode(ros_master);
        printf("Advertising cmd_vel message\n");
        geometry_msgs::Twist twist_msg;
        ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("cmd_vel", &twist_msg);
        nh.advertise(cmd_vel_pub);

        printf("Go robot go!\n");
        while (1)
        {
          twist_msg.linear.x = x;
          twist_msg.linear.y = y;
          twist_msg.linear.z = z;
          twist_msg.angular.x = 0;
          twist_msg.angular.y = 0;
          twist_msg.angular.z = -1.8;
          cmd_vel_pub.publish(&twist_msg);

          nh.spinOnce();
          Sleep(100);
        }

        printf("All done!\n");
        return 0;
     }
}
```

Do someone know that I did wrong?
Most of the errors appears in the files log.h, node_handle.h .
And then there is one warning
Warning    C4273   'SendMsg::Message::sendingMsg': inconsistent dll linkage

EDIT:
I found the following interesting [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b87d5784-cbb8-44d3-a3e3-39688649b31f/struct-problem?forum=vclanguage)

Here several errors like C2238, C2143, C2059 appeared during compiling just like at my program.

The best answer in that post was to start a empty project with just putting the include's in it. I did this and in addition to that I add ros_lib to my project as
[described](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Hello%20World).

The header which causes all the errors was ros.h.
When I tested the tutorial Hello World, I used a WIN32 console application and eyerthing worked fine.
So the problem is how to get a dll of that.
What have to be done what it works ?
Has someone an idea?

It seems that ros_lib is not compatible with VS2015. What do you think ?

I thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258617/publishing-a-node-by-using-a-dll-in-visual-basic-2015(windows)/) by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I solved my problem, I comment out the #include "stdafx.h" and then it works. In addition to that I add __cdecl and made same changes. Here is my code:

```
#include <string>    
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ros.h"
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <windows.h>
extern "C"
{

    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    char *ros_master = "192.168.1.4";
    geometry_msgs::Twist twist_msg;
    ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("cmd_vel", &twist_msg);

    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl InitRosPublish() 
    {
        printf("Connecting to server at %s\n", ros_master);
        nh.initNode(ros_master);
        printf("Advertising cmd_vel message\n");
        nh.advertise(cmd_vel_pub);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl PublishImuData(double roll, double pitch, double yaw)
    {
        printf("Go robot go!\n");
        twist_msg.linear.x = x;
        twist_msg.linear.y = y;
        twist_msg.linear.z = z;
        twist_msg.angular.x = 0;
        twist_msg.angular.y = 0;
        twist_msg.angular.z = -1.8;
        cmd_vel_pub.publish(&twist_msg);
        nh.spinOnce();
        Sleep(10);
        printf("All done!\n");
    }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) with karma: 43 on 2017-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0